# PHP in Mac OS X: PHP loads source code in browser rather than executing…

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mac-osx, httpd

I don't know what to do. I read the related question on stackoverflow just like mine but those changes didn't work. I asked again on stackoverflow and they sent me here. They sent that I need to load my PHP module, but I've done that (at least to  my knowledge). Here is what I posed to them:

First, I edited the httpd.conf file and uncommented `LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache2/libphp5.so` .

Next after getting this error "/usr/sbin/apachectl: line 82: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument" I changed `ULIMIT_MAX_FILES="ulimit -S -n ulimit -H` -n to `ULIMIT_MAX_FILES=""` or some odd thing. That resolved that error.

However I still just see my source code in Safari (actually Chrome decided to download the PHP file instead--different problem/story). Then I found a question similar to mine on stackoverflow and added some `AddHandler` lines to the php5.conf file which mimicked the `AddType` lines in the file after `AddHandler`. Still didn't work even after a "sudo apachectl restart".

Then I finally added `AddType x-httpd-php .php` to the httpd.conf file because that was also mentioned in the previous question on stackoverflow. I did it just for good measure. Nada.

I'm baffled. I'm just trying to get started so I can learn to program and I feel like I've spent a lifetime just trying to print 'Hello World' in my browser.

Comment: Please give us your configuration (formatted as a code block so it comes out readable) so we can see what's gone wrong.  The symptoms tell us that apache doesn't think that `whatever.php` needs to be passed to mod_php for processing, but the changes you made should fix it.  Other things to check: is the file you're editing the same file apache is using?

Comment: What exact URL are you trying to go to when you see your source code?

Comment: Oh Jesus... no wonder. All this time I was just opening it as a file. I should have gotten more sleep last night. Thanks.

Comment: I know it sounds kind of obvious but did you remember to reload the config or restart Apache?

Comment: @Storm Sometimes, it's the obvious things that trip you up :)

Comment: Yeah John I did the less obvious things and ignored the most. @Matt Indeed. I blame allergies. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to program, and want something that 'just works', you may consider just doing a MAMP [(Mac, Apache, MySQL, PHP stack)](http://www.mamp.info/en/mamp/index.html) install and moving on. I've used it a few times under Leopard and it did the trick.

Comment: Oh I see.. I thought MAMP was just a general name for this combination of platforms, which I thought I was using. I didn't realize this was a download.

Comment: @Storm: It is a general name for that combination, but there are packaged solutions that put everything together preconfigured.  This one happens to be named MAMP

Comment: Here's my problem now: I have MAMP up and running, phpversion works through their link. MAMP tells me things are working, yet a simple Hello World .php file just shows me the code in the browser. How can this be a server issue still? I'm baffled.

Comment: Well at least some other poor morons will have this as a resource.